# PHP flush() function and content-type: text/event-stream

Tags: php

From what I understand, this function - flush () - pushes the output to the browser. Assuming I have a code 30 command lines and put a flush () on the 15th line, the server would force push or interpreted code until the 14th line for my browser? Would that be? This question arose because I'm trying to make use of HTML5 SSE. The idea is to make the server send updates to the browser every time there is update the database, without the need to send a request to the server.

Comment: You can't send updates from the server to the browser, if the browser doesn't make a request. At least not with PHP.

Comment: I use event stream to send data to the browser